# HttpLoggingInterceptor does not show any logs

Tags: android, retrofit2

trying to use HttpLoggingInterceptor with Retrofit2, but have no result, any requests/responses doesn't show any logs.

There are libraries' versions i use:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
```

There is code where i'm generating api instance:

```
public class ApiGenerator {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
    private static final String API_KEY = "de4d4a35830d98e785a1cbb06725457f";

    private ApiGenerator() {}

    public static WeatherApi createWeatherApi() {
        return createRetrofit().create(WeatherApi.class);
    }

    private static Retrofit createRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(createClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    private static OkHttpClient createClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request request = chain.request();
            HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("APPID", API_KEY)
                    .build();
            request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        })
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your example is using a default logger which you may not have configured. A better solution would be to pass in a custom logger using your logging framework of choice. [Example using SLF4J with Logback](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttpclient-logging-configuration-with-interceptors).

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClient.class);

private static final HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor =
    new HttpLoggingInterceptor((msg) -> {
        log.debug(msg);
    });
static {
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(Level.BODY);
}

public static HttpLoggingInterceptor getLoggingInterceptor() {
    return loggingInterceptor;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A Kotlin version of Bill's answer

```kotlin
val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("HttpLogging")
val okHttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor { log.debug(it) }.setLevel(BODY)
```